# How to divide all of my specific cells in MS excel to a value in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have price list of items in some specific currency in MS Excel. While sending it to customer , I want the price list to be displayed in their domestic currency.

I have put the exchange rate in one cell. Now, paste special option in excel do let me divide all the price by my exchange rate but the resultant is the value and not formula. For example, if my exchange rate is 70 in cell 'A1' and the local price is 700 in cell 'A2', by pasting special and choosing divide option, I get the value 10 in cell 'A2' but what I want is to get 700/$A$1.

This will give me flexibility to change rates as per the market. Please suggest how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be to introduce a third cell that contains the formula `=$A$2/$A$1`. This way the original value is still visible and can be changed without manipulating a formula.

If you really want to have the cell A2 to contain the formula `=700/$A$1`, you can achieve this in VBA like this:

```
Range("A2").Formula = "=" & Range("A2") & "/$A$1"
```

To apply this to a list of values, create a loop and replace the range object and cell reference in the formula accordingly.

Be aware that this code cannot be run repeatedly because you change the content of cell A2.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the VBA option. Introducing the third cell is clean solution but, it doesn't serve the purpose. There are many derivative prices dependent of the primary price. Only changing the primary price would change all other prices in my sheet.